# Not able connect to Google API client from Wearable Fragment

Tags: android, android-wear-data-api

I created a fragment in Wearable app where I need to send message to Handheld using message API of Google API client. The google is not connected and it always displays log as "not connected". I added meta data to manifest on Wearable side.
Please find the below code and help in connecting to Google API client from Wearable app.
 One more query do we need to have listener service when we want to send message from wearable to Handheld?

## BlankFragment.java

```
package com.andr.assestdatatransferdemo;


import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataEventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, DataApi.DataListener, MessageApi.MessageListener,
        NodeApi.NodeListener{
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private static final String START_ACTIVITY_PATH = "/start-activity";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/image";


    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
            Log.d("TAG","Connected");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("TAG","Not Connected");
        }
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerConnected(Node node) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPeerDisconnected(Node node) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andr.assestdatatransferdemo" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <service
            android:name=".DataLayerListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable"
            android:required="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can any one help me in finding the mistake I was doing for which I always gets the message as not connected on onCreateView() method?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the onConnected you setup?

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }
```

to retrieve the connection state? Probably on onCreateView() the GoogleApiClient was not yet connected.

You already declared a WearableListenerService to take care of all the incoming messages, so you may no need to implement all the other Listener

> DataApi.DataListener, MessageApi.MessageListener

.

```
<service
            android:name=".DataLayerListenerService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

To send a Message to the Handheld or Smartwatch use the following code:

```
private void sendMessage(final String path, final String text) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mApiClient).await();
            for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, node.getId(), path, text.getBytes()).await();
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

It is reccomended to use a thread because the operation may require some time blocking the UI.